# Filter two tables with crosstalk

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, flexdashboard

I am creating a Flexdashboard in R. I want the dashboard to contains both a table and a series of visualizations, that would be filtered through inputs.

As I need to deliver a dashboard locally (without a server running in the background), I am unable to use Shiny, hence I rely on crosstalk.

I know that the crosstalk package provides limited functionality in the front-end. For instance, the documentation says that you can't aggregate the SharedData object.

Nonetheless, I am not clear if I can use the **same inputs to filter two different dataframes**.

For example, lets say I have:

1. Dataframe One: Contains original data

   ```
   df1 <- structure(list(owner = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", 
   "Mark"), class = "factor"), hp = c(250, 120, 250, 100, 110), 
   car = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("benz", 
   "bmw"), class = "factor"), id = structure(1:5, .Label = c("car1", 
   "car2", "car3", "car4", "car5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("owner", 
   "hp", "car", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
   ```
2. Dataframe Two: Contains aggregated data

   ```
   df2 <- structure(list(car = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("benz", 
   + "bmw"), class = "factor"), owner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
   + ), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), class = "factor"), freq = c(0L, 
   + 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("car", "owner", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
   + -4L), class = "data.frame")
   ```

These two dataframes contain **columns with identical values - car and owner**. As well as, additional columns too.

I could create two different objects:

```
library(crosstalk)
shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(df1)
shared_df2 <- SharedData$new(df2)
```

and than:

```
filter_select("owner", "Car owner:", shared_df1, ~ owner)
filter_select("owner", "Car owner:", shared_df2, ~ owner)
```

However, that would mean that the user will need to fill inputs that are essentially identical, twice. Also, if the table is large, this would double the size of the memory needed to use the dashboard.

Is it possible to work around this problem in crosstalk?

Comment: As far as I read about Crosstalk, it allows to create filters from single dataframe(shareddata). In order to make it work on two dataframes, one will be requrired to create only one shareddata using joins .  However, I would love to know other way to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ah I recently ran into this too, there is another argument to `SharedData$new(..., group = )`! The group argument seems to do the trick. I found out by accident when I had two dataframes and used the `group =`.

If you make a sharedData object, it will include

- a dataframe
- a key to select rows by - preferably unique, but not necessarily.
- a group name

What I think happens is that crosstalk filters the sharedData by the key - for all sharedData objects in the same group! So as long as two dataframes use the same key, you should be able to filter them together in one group.

This should work for your example.

````
---
title: "blabla"
output:
   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   orientation: rows
   social: menu
   source_code: embed
   theme: cerulean
---

```{r}
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r Make dataset}
df1 <- structure(list(owner = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), class = "factor"), hp = c(250, 120, 250, 100, 110), car = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("benz", "bmw"), class = "factor"), id = structure(1:5, .Label = c("car1", "car2", "car3", "car4", "car5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("owner", "hp", "car", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(car = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("benz", 
"bmw"), class = "factor"), owner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), class = "factor"), freq = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("car", "owner", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

#

##

### Filters

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
# Notice the 'group = ' argument - this does the trick!
shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(df1, ~owner, group = "Choose owner")
shared_df2 <- SharedData$new(df2, ~owner, group = "Choose owner")

filter_select("owner", "Car owner:", shared_df1, ~owner)
# You don't need this second filter now
# filter_select("owner", "Car owner:", shared_df2, ~ owner)
```

### Plot1 with plotly

```{r}
plot_ly(shared_df1, x = ~id, y = ~hp, color = ~owner) %>% add_markers() %>% highlight("plotly_click")
```

### Plots with plotly

```{r}
plot_ly(shared_df2, x = ~owner, y = ~freq, color = ~car) %>% group_by(owner) %>% add_bars()
```

##

### Dataframe 1

```{r}
DT::datatable(shared_df1)
```

### Dataframe 2

```{r}
DT::datatable(shared_df2)
```
````

I spent some time on this by trying to extract data from `plot_ly()` using `plotly_data()` without luck until I figured out the answer. That's why there's some very simple plots with plotly.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for the help!

Comment: great answer! can you please take a look at my question if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699881/interactive-plots-in-r thank you

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've also wanted to use one filter to filter 2 visualizations.

**Brief description of my situation** 
I've wanted to use one filter to filter a boxplot and a table. 
Source data has been a data frame. I've wanted to use some of variables for the boxplot and also calculate some statistics (like mean, standard deviation, mode, number of records). 
Functions I've needed to use to display results: plotly::plot_ly(), DT::datatable(), crosstalk::bscols().

I've found out that there are **3 key information** to solve this situation 
*Key 1)* It's necessary to **correctly** create shared data. 
In my case, I've had to use crosstalk::SharedData$new() twice. 
Correct shared data, to be used as source for visualizations, can be used if firstly keys 2 and 3 are fulfilled. 
*Key 2)* When creating shared data, use the same group argument as "Lodewic Van Twillert" explained on 16 Mar 2018. 
*Key 3)* Ensure that all SharedData instances refer conceptually to the same data points, and share the same keys. 
Start with ensuring that a data frame has row names even if row names are character vector with numbers (like "1", "2", ...). 
Used literature for this key 3: https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/using.html. (I suggest to mainly read subtitle "Grouping".)

**Summary of steps** I've used to fulfill key information from above 
*Key 3)* This one could be tricky in order to fulfill relevant conditions of key 3 above. 
The approach I've chosen creates one table containing all data and this table (data frame) will be used to create both shared data. 
I've applied data manipulations to original data frame (risk_scores_df) so now this data has a new column. 
I've created a new data frame with statistics. 
I've joined both data frames using
`risk_scores_df <- dplyr::left_join...` so now the original data frame contains all prepared data. 
I've run `print(rownames(risk_scores_df))` to ensure that my updated data frame has row names. 
Now, I've had one data frame containing all data (needed for both visualizations) that fulfill conditions of information of key 3 above. 
*Key 2)* I've simply added `group = "sd1"` in both crosstalk::SharedData$new() 
*Key 1)* This one could be also tricky if a wrong approach is chosen. 
Here, the key to create **correct** shared data instances is to use that one table with all data and choose only rows and columns needed for a relevant shared data. 
Example - in my case, I've run codes in Option 1 to create two shared data instances, but also Option 2 is possible.

Option 1 (choosing of only needed rows and columns is in crosstalk::SharedData$new())

```
  rs_df_sd1 <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(
    risk_scores_df[, c(1, 2, 5)],
    group = "sd1"
  )
  rs_df_sd1a <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(
    risk_scores_df[risk_scores_df$NumRecords > 0 &
                   is.na(risk_scores_df$NumRecords) == F,
                   c(1, 6:11)],
    group = "sd1"
  )
```

Option 2 (choosing of only needed rows and columns is in additional variables)

```
  sd1 <- risk_scores_df[, c(1, 2, 5)]
  sd1a <- risk_scores_df[risk_scores_df$NumRecords > 0 &
                         is.na(risk_scores_df$NumRecords) == F,
                         c(1, 6:11)]

  rs_df_sd1 <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(sd1, group = "sd1")
  rs_df_sd1a <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(sd1a, group = "sd1")
```

**Completing the solution** 
At this point I've created shared data instances rs_df_sd1 and rs_df_sd1a that can be used as main sources for visualizations that will be filtered using crosstalk::bscols(). 
Brief example:

```
  box_n_jitter_chart1 <- plotly::plot_ly(rs_df_sd1) %>% add_trace(...
  DT_table1 <- DT::datatable(rs_df_sd1a)
  crosstalk::bscols(
    widths = c(6, 12, NA),
    crosstalk::filter_select(
      id = "idAvgRisk",
      label = "Account",
      sharedData = rs_df_sd1,
      group = ~Account,
      multiple = F
    ),
    box_n_jitter_chart1,
    DT_table1
  )
```

Note: DT::datatable() can also use  `rs_df_sd1a$data()` and `cells = list(values = base::rbind(...` (see that `cells = ...` is used; see more about using `cells` e.g. at https://plotly.com/r/reference/table/) but because `method data()` is used (see more e.g. at https://rdrr.io/cran/crosstalk/man/SharedData.html#method-data) then it will not work with crosstalk::bscols.

Comment: I'd really like to test this example - any chance you can make it reproducible with example data for those dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example (with Markdown vs flexdashboard, but you could add that part later), using a plot and a table filtering to the same city, e.g., Austin. This is a good example of where you could combine data from two separate sources in the same table (e.g., txhousing), then separate them with a filter, then use group to filter them both.

````
---
title: "Two linked objects demo"
date: "2024-03-26"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r libraries, warning = F, message = F, quietly = T}
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)
```


### Filter plot to city of interest

```{r, fig.height = 3}

# load the `txhousing` dataset
data(txhousing, package = "ggplot2")

# create two "separate" datasets from the first one so they reference the same row ids.
tx1 <- txhousing %>% filter(year < 2008)
tx2 <- txhousing %>% filter(month == 1, inventory > 5)

# Create two shared objects with the same group name
shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(tx1, ~city, group = "Choose a city")
shared_df2 <- SharedData$new(tx2, ~city, group = "Choose a city")

# Create a plot
gg <- ggplot(shared_df1) + geom_line(aes(date, median, group = city))
filter_select("id", "City:", shared_df1, ~city, multiple = FALSE)
ggplotly(gg, dynamicTicks = TRUE)

```

### Table

```{r}
# show a table with related data
DT::datatable(shared_df2)
```
````

[image: Markdown document showing a line plot of Austin's data over time, and table with Austin's data for month 1]