# Two keys to filter on with crosstalk

Tags: r, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I am wondering if it is possible to filter the data on a second attribute/key when using `crosstalk::SharedData`?

I would like to modify the example:

[Filter two tables with crosstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581598/filter-two-tables-with-crosstalk/49327147#49327147)

to introduce an additional variable e.g. `sex`,  and to have an additional `select_filter`, which will enable me to subset the data by `sex` (male, female) first, before in addition selecting by `owner`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this by adding some `filter_checkbox()`'s and `filter_select()`'s. When I display these with `bscols(filter_checkbox("sex", "Select sex", dt, ~sex), ggplotly(ggplot(dt, x = x, y = y), dynamicTicks = TRUE))` I can first filter based on the checkboxes and then still highlight things in the plot.