# Show empty table before filtering with crosstalk

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard, reactable, crosstalk

I would like to filter a reactable with crosstalk. Let's say I have the following Rmd-file:

````
---
title: "blabla"
output:
   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   orientation: rows
   social: menu
   source_code: embed
   theme: cerulean
---

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r Make dataset}
df1 <- structure(list(owner = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), 
class = "factor"), hp = c(250, 120, 250, 100, 110), car = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("benz", "bmw"), class = "factor"), id = structure(1:5, .Label = c("car1", "car2", "car3", "car4", "car5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("owner", "hp", "car", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(car = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("benz", 
"bmw"), class = "factor"), owner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), class = "factor"), freq = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("car", "owner", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

#

##

### Filters

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
# Notice the 'group = ' argument - this does the trick!
shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(df1, ~owner, group = "Choose owner")
shared_df2 <- SharedData$new(df2, ~owner, group = "Choose owner")

filter_select("owner", "Car owner:", shared_df1, ~owner)
```


##

### Dataframe 1

```{r}
reactable::reactable(shared_df1)
```

### Dataframe 2

```{r}
reactable::reactable(shared_df2)
```
````

Now before the user enters a car owner the table shows the rows for all car owners. I would like to achieve that the table is empty, and only if a car owner is entered, the table should show the information for this car owner. Is this possible to achieve? I am looking for a solution without Shiny.

The example above is deduced from: [Filter two tables with crosstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581598/filter-two-tables-with-crosstalk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with crosstalk and tried to search for their docs and maybe this is not supported. BUT, we can do it with some javascripts.

```js
function toggleDF(hasItem, selector) {
    if(!hasItem) {
        $(selector).hide();
    } else {
        $(selector).show();
    }
}
$(function(){
    // hide on start
    toggleDF(false, '#dataframe-1 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
    toggleDF(false, '#dataframe-2 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
    $('#owner').on("change", function(){
        var hasItem = $(this).find('.selectize-input').hasClass('has-items');
        // hide/show based on selection
        toggleDF(hasItem, '#dataframe-1 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
        toggleDF(hasItem, '#dataframe-2 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
    });
});
```

1. A function `toggleDF` to show and hide the table body.
2. Some expressions to trigger the function based on whether you have selections in the `owner` dropdown.
3. In the expression, it requires you to put the reactable under certain title so we can find the ID, eg `### Dataframe 2`'s ID is `dataframe-2`, lower case of all letters and dash replace spaces (how Rmarkdown translate titles to IDs).

Full code

````
---
title: "blabla"
output:
   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   orientation: rows
   social: menu
   source_code: embed
   theme: cerulean
---

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r Make dataset}
df1 <- structure(list(owner = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), 
class = "factor"), hp = c(250, 120, 250, 100, 110), car = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("benz", "bmw"), class = "factor"), id = structure(1:5, .Label = c("car1", "car2", "car3", "car4", "car5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("owner", "hp", "car", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(car = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("benz", 
"bmw"), class = "factor"), owner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("John", "Mark"), class = "factor"), freq = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("car", "owner", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

#

##

### Filters

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
# Notice the 'group = ' argument - this does the trick!
shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(df1, ~owner, group = "Choose owner")
shared_df2 <- SharedData$new(df2, ~owner, group = "Choose owner")

filter_select("owner", "Car owner:", shared_df1, ~owner)
```


##

### Dataframe 1

```{r}
reactable::reactable(shared_df1)
```

### Dataframe 2

```{r}
reactable::reactable(shared_df2)
```

<script>
function toggleDF(hasItem, selector) {
    if(!hasItem) {
        $(selector).hide();
    } else {
        $(selector).show();
    }
}
$(function(){
    // hide on start
    toggleDF(false, '#dataframe-1 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
    toggleDF(false, '#dataframe-2 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
    $('#owner').on("change", function(){
        var hasItem = $(this).find('.selectize-input').hasClass('has-items');
        // hide/show based on selection
        toggleDF(hasItem, '#dataframe-1 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
        toggleDF(hasItem, '#dataframe-2 .ReactTable .rt-tbody');
    });
});
</script>
````

[image: screenshot]